# Non-divergence form to divergence form.

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

Consider 1-dimensional boundary-value problem 
$$
\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{array}{lr}
 -a(x)u_{xx} + b(x) u_x + c(x) u = f, 0<x<L \\
u(0) = u(L) = 0
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}
$$
where $0<c_1 \le a(x) \le c_2$.
Can it be transformed in to the divergence form as follows?
$$
\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{array}{lr}
 -(\tilde{a}(x)u_{x})_x + \tilde{c}(x) u = \tilde{f}, 0<x<L \\
u(0) = u(L) = 0
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}
$$
I don't understand how come the term $u_x$ can vanish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$u_x$ did not "vanish". Note from the product rule:

$$ -(\bar{a}u_x)_x + \bar{c}u = -(\bar{a}u_{xx} + \bar{a}_xu_x) + \bar{c}u $$

Thus we can choose an integrating factor $\mu(x)$ (refer back to first-order ODEs for derivations) such that

$$ -(\mu a u_{xx} - \mu bu_x) + \mu cu = -(\bar{a}u_{xx} + \bar{a}_xu_x) + \bar{c}u $$

For this to hold, we require
$$ (\mu a)_x = -\mu b $$

Solving the first-order ODE for $\mu$ gives
$$ \mu_x a + \mu (a_x + b) = 0 $$
$$ \mu = -\int \frac{a_x+b}{a} dx $$